# How To Remount Raid 1 Array After OS Disk Failed

Tags: linux-mint, raid

Have a workstation that has an SSD for the boot drive (Linux Mint) and (software) Raid 1 array  for data storage. The SSD died, and I've replaced it and reinstalled Mint.

How do I get the OS to recognize and mount the Raid 1 Array at boot? I'm comfortable at the CLI, just don't know how to get this done.

Comment: P.S. The data array was mounted as /home.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is ensuring that the RAID array gets activated at boot.

First run:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

If the output includes the status of your RAID array, the system has already auto-detected and -activated it. If there is only one line about RAID personalities and another about unused devices, then the array hasn't been activated. You'll need to fix that first.

Make sure you have the `mdadm` package installed, and you may want to add an `ARRAY` line to `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`; the output of the command `sudo mdadm --examine --scan` should be helpful here. Then update your initramfs with `sudo update-initramfs -u`, and reboot.

Once the RAID array is getting activated automatically at boot, you'll just need to write a line in `/etc/fstab` for the `/home` filesystem that's on your RAID array. After editing `/etc/fstab`, it's time to shift the current `/home/` directory aside, create a new empty directory for a mountpoint, and mount the `/home/` filesystem:

```
cd /
sudo mv /home /home.temporary
sudo mkdir /home
sudo mount -a
```

If `sudo mount -a` fails, move `/home.temporary` back to `/home` and then troubleshoot the filesystem on the RAID array.